# Split a column time into 2 (Time,Date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can i reformat this code to split results column  time into 2 (Time,Date)

```
SELECT 
DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, DATEADD(s, 2, dbo.roundtime
       (CallStartTime, 1
       ))), 0) AS [Time], COUNT(DISTINCT [CallID]) AS [Sum of Calls]
FROM [Database].[dbo].[table]
WHERE CallStartTime BETWEEN '8/2/2015' AND '2/2/2016'
      AND
      CompanyID NOT IN
                       (718, 722, 1769, 1886, 2518, 2519, 2533, 2544, 2766, 2877, 3603, 3604, 4785, 5674, 5675, 5676, 5677, 5678, 5679, 5680, 5681,
                       5682, 5683, 5684, 5685, 5686, 5687, 5688, 5689, 5690, 5691, 5692, 9021, 9492, 9884, 4785, 11059, 11777, 11779, 13194
                       )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Convert is your friend:

```
select convert(char(10), getdate(), 120) dateComponent
, convert(char(5), getdate(), 108) timeComponent
```

**Edit starts here:**

For your question:

```
select convert(char(10), time, 120) dateComponent
, convert(char(5), time, 108) timeComponent
, "sum of calls"
from 
(sql from the question goes here) temp
```

Comment: sorry ive never done it before , how to add that into the statement i have?

Comment: is there is a time function,like casting it as time?

Comment: Possibly, if your sql server version is sufficiently recent.  I could look it up, but then again, so could you.